# SQL Select Between Two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

```
    T1:

    ref || Name
    ===========
     1  ||  A
     2  ||  B
     3  ||  C
     4  ||  D
     5  ||  E
```

And

```
    T2:

    ref || Name
    ===========
     1  ||  w
     2  ||  x
     6  ||  y
     7  ||  z
```

I need this result:

```
    Name1 || Name2
    ==============
     A    ||  w
     B    ||  x
     C    ||  y
     D    ||  z
     E    ||  NULL
```

I mean some kind of full outer join, on column ref, that will not produce NULL value until there is not any record.
The priority of join is with the values that have same ref, and if row count of tables are not equal, there are some NULL results

Comment: Reword please, everyone is clearly tripping over your explanation. Also, from your results it seems like you want like ID columns to have their own column (not row). Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every body and excuse me if I speak badly sometimes, count it on my fatigue because of hours working.
I think I couldn't say my meaning correctly, so I answered my own question. this is not the best answer and it is not optimized, I know, but it works!

```
SELECT t.ref,
   t.NAME         AS n1,
   t2.NAME        AS n2
INTO   #tbl1
FROM   @T1            AS t
   LEFT JOIN @T2  AS t2
        ON  t2.ref = t.ref
WHERE  t2.ref IS NOT NULL

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.NAME) AS rn,
   *
INTO           #tbl2
FROM   @T1  AS t
WHERE  t.ref NOT IN (SELECT ref
                 FROM   #tbl1)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.NAME) AS rn,
   *
INTO           #tbl3
FROM   @T2  AS t
WHERE  t.ref NOT IN (SELECT ref
                 FROM   #tbl1)

SELECT n1,
   n2
FROM   #tbl1
UNION
SELECT t1.NAME  AS n1,
   t2.NAME  AS n2
FROM   #tbl2 t1
   FULL OUTER JOIN #tbl3 t2
        ON  t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UPD: here is how you may combine values by values count from different tables:

```
with t1_values as (
    SELECT
       name,
       row_number() over (order by ref) as position
    FROM #t1
),
t2_values as (
    SELECT
       name,
       row_number() over (order by ref) as position
    FROM #t2
)

SELECT
   t1_values.name as name1,
   t2_values.name as name2
FROM t1_values
left JOIN t2_values on t1_values.position = t2_values.position
```

Comment: I know what is LEFT JOIN!!!!! Please read the question again!
your result is:
(A,w)
(B,x)
(C,NULL)
(D,NULL)
(E,NULL)

Comment: I see now. Will rewrite answer now.

Comment: Corrected answer, please check it out.

Comment: not the correct answer, if we change T1 as (10,A) (11,B) (3,C) (4,D) (5,E)  and T2 (5, X) (others without change) then we need to have pair of (E, X) in result

Comment: Why E should be paired with x? They have different ref value, and if order both tables by name, then it shouldn't match either.

Comment: Hi @ArashGhasemiRad you are asking for help and you are using `!` that sounds you are yelling on the Aleksey. Second thing is you are asking for basic sql and yet, you have not provided any clues on what you have done so far... Think again

Comment: excuse me because of that '!'  I didn't mean that.

Answer (score 2):

This is very complicated.  You want rows that match to match.  Then you want unmatched rows to match unmatched rows by position, and then everything else.

```
with matches as (
      select distinct t1.ref
      from t1
      where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.ref = t1.ref)
     ),
     tt1 as (
      select t1.*, m.ref as match_ref,
             row_number() over (partition by m.ref order by t1.ref) as alt_ref
      from t1 left join
           matches m
           on t1.ref = m.ref
     ),
     tt2 as (
      select t2.*, m.ref as match_ref,
             row_number() over (partition by m.ref order by t2.ref) as alt_ref
      from t2 left join
           matches m
           on t2.ref = m.ref
     )
select tt1.name, tt2.name
from tt1 left join
     tt2
     on tt1.match_ref = tt2.match_ref or
        (tt1.match_ref is null and tt2.match_ref is null and tt1.alt_ref = tt2.alt_ref);
```

Here is the idea.  For each row in both tables, add two new columns:

- `match_ref` is `ref` when `ref` exists in the other table.
- `alt_ref` is an enumerated column for the `ref` values that do not match.

Once you have these columns, it is possible to join the tables together, by first checking `match_ref` and then -- if that is not present -- checking `alt.ref`.

SQL Fiddle does not appear to be working for SQL Server.  However, [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9642) is an identical Postgres version that does work.  [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/507253) is a working version using SQL Server (this is identical to the Postgres version).

Comment: what is t3 (on t3.ref = m.ref)?!

Comment: this returns (C, ...) three times with Y , W , X

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad . . . I have run this in SQL Fiddle (using Postgres) and it works correctly.  Postgres and SQL Server should be identical for this functionality.

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad . . . It works for me in both SQL Server and Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

- A look at your Question

Correct me if I am wrong, but you have two tables that have an reference ID column of names that you wish to return results sets....only, you do not say distinct so you might end up with extras.

> ...some kind of full outer join, on column ref, that will not
>   produce NULL value until there is not any record..
>   The priority of the JOIN is with the values that have same ref, and if row count of tables are
>   not equal, there are some NULL results

Actually, the result is not really deterministic. Anyways, this question is still too vague. However, I think you really just want rows matching columns to appear together and anything not....well, not. But return everything.

So, if you know which side is larger, try this:

```
WITH C AS (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY NAME DESC) AS ROW_ID
                , ref
                , Name AS Name1
           FROM T1)

SELECT Name1, B.Name2
FROM   C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DENSE_RANK() (OVER PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY NAME DESC) AS ROW_ID
               , ref
               , Name AS Name2) B ON B.Row_ID = C.Row_ID AND B.ref = C.ref
```

Each of the ref columns have a distinct ID to attach with. It is done in consecutive order, so if there is still an issue, well, you can figure that logic out. But I'm sure this will help you tremendously get where you are wanting. :)